# Auto generate / convert strings.xml from all used "text"?

Tags: android

what is the easiest way in Android to convert a fix text in xml to strings.xml - I have a lots of them in my project, so would take big time to do it one by one^^

Comment: You could write a shell script.

Comment: world you like to share what have you tried so far??